# JavaScript(Jquery) slider for questionnaire

Tags: javascript, jquery

im need very simplest code example to do simple carusel(for questionnaire)
for example im have next simple html code

```
<div>screen1<div>
<div>screen2<div>
<div>screen3<div>
<button>Prev</button>
<button>Next</button>
```

prev button must appear if im on all screen without screen1

Comment: We need to see some code that you've tried to achieve this target

Answer (score 0):

have a look to a very simple  slider

[cycle2 slider](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/prevnext.php)